# In project templates area only 3 templates are available. How can i get other templates

Tags: dart

In dart editor -> project templates area only 3 templates are available. 
Command - line application, package template and web application create. How to get other templates. when first installed its there, don't know what is missing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but I think running

```
pub global activate stagehand
```

from the command line should make additional templates available.

DartEditor isn't supported since quite some time and might not work with recent Dart version. It may be better to switch to Atom, WebStorm, IntelliJ, Sublime Text, ...

Comment: Thanks man. You are right, I'm switching back to the older version sdk 1.15.0